# cloudControl - PHP: (temporarily) disable composer

Tags: composer-php, cloudcontrol

I am happily developing a PHP app using [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) on cloudControl. 
It's great how it is integrated into the deployment procedure.
However, there's no need for Composer to update on *every* deploy.

Is it possible to (temporarily) disable Composer, per deployment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely familiar with how cloudControl integrated Composer, but ideally you run should `composer update` when you see fit, and then commit your composer.lock file, and they would run `composer install` on every deploy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't committing the lock file yet. Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean composer updating itself: right now the latest version of composer is downloaded on every push, *unless* you have one already. Just place the composer.phar file in your project directory and it will be used instead.

Comment: Thanks! Including the composer.phar file certainly speeds it up a bit.